# Magento Migration 1.9.2.0 to Magento 2.3.2 from CLI

Tags: magento, magento2, database-migration, data-migration

I am trying to migrate website from Magento 19.2.0 to Magento 2.3.2 using CLI. I have made all changes in config.xml file with path to both database and here is the command i am trying to execute to apply settings.

```
php bin/magento migrate:settings --reset vendor/magento/data-migration-tool/etc/opensource-to-opensource/1.9.2.0/config.xml
```

would be great if someone suggest the fix for this error.

> In Dom.php line 455:
>
> AttValue: " or ' expected   Line: 110
>
> attributes construct error   Line: 110
>
> Couldn't find end of Start Tag database line 110   Line: 110
>
> AttValue: " or ' expected   Line: 113
>
> attributes construct error   Line: 113
>
> Couldn't find end of Start Tag database line 113   Line: 113

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar error, check your config.xml in line 110, I just forget a closing "

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem changing the database password.
I removed all special characters from the password and the import worked fine! There is some password field at the config.xml in my case